# Does freezing one's credit report freeze both the report and the score or just the score?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

If I place a security freeze on my credit report, does that prevent a lender from accessing the report and my credit score or does it just prevent accessing the credit score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A freeze prevents a new lender from accessing your report.  It does not prevent an existing lender from accessing it.  See [the FTC explanation](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0497-credit-freeze-faqs#score).

> **What is a credit freeze?**
>
> Also known as a security freeze, this tool lets you restrict access to
>   your credit report, which in turn makes it more difficult for identity
>   thieves to open new accounts in your name. That’s because most
>   creditors need to see your credit report before they approve a new
>   account. If they can’t see your file, they may not extend the credit.
>
> **Does a credit freeze affect my credit score?**
>
> No. A credit freeze does not affect your credit score.
>
> A credit freeze also does not:
>
> - prevent you from getting your free annual credit report
> - keep you from opening a new account, applying for a job, renting an apartment, or buying insurance. But if you’re doing any of these,
>     you’ll need to lift the freeze temporarily, either for a specific time
>     or for a specific party, say, a potential landlord or employer. The
>     cost and lead times to lift a freeze vary, so it’s best to check with
>     the credit reporting company in advance.
> - prevent a thief from making charges to your existing accounts. You still need to monitor all bank, credit card and insurance statements
>     for fraudulent transactions.
>
> **Can anyone see my credit report if it is frozen?**
>
> Certain entities still will have access to it.
>
> - your report can be released to your existing creditors or to debt collectors acting on their behalf.
> - government agencies may have access in response to a court or administrative order, a subpoena, or a search warrant.